# Python requests code snippet from Postman

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

I am trying to check if an email already exists in a website. Currently using a sample Python code from Postman.

sample code that works:

```
import requests

url = "https://registration.mercadolivre.com.br/registration/"

payload = "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"signUp.email\"\r\n\r\ntest@hotmail.com\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"signUp.repEmail\"\r\n\r\ntest@hotmail.com\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"signUp.newsletter\"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\"\r\n\r\nmercadolibre\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--"
headers = {
'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'postman-token': "179cabe2-dd22-490e-8fbd-15bf2977feb5"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I am not sure why is Postman encoding the payload in that string. when I try passing a dictionary it does not work anymore

Code that does not work:

```
import requests

url = "https://registration.mercadolivre.com.br/registration/"

payload = { 'signUp.email': 'test@hotmail.com',
 'signUp.repEmail': 'test@hotmail.com',
 'signUp.newsletter': 'true',
 'source': 'mercadolibre' }
headers = {
'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'postman-token': "22a12fa5-5f68-685c-124d-db0ef6eb334c"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I am wondering why I can't pass a json or dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

your json version works fine

```
import requests

url = "https://registration.mercadolivre.com.br/registration/"

payload = { 'signUp.email': 'test@hotmail.com',
 'signUp.repEmail': 'test@hotmail.com',
 'signUp.newsletter': 'true',
 'source': 'mercadolibre' }
headers = {
'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'postman-token': "22a12fa5-5f68-685c-124d-db0ef6eb334c"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

> Output

```
> python payload.py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="es-AR" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 ie6"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]> <html lang="es-AR" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="es-AR" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 ie8"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="es-AR" class="no-js lt-ie10 ie9"> <![endif]--><!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]> <!--> <html lang="es-AR" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><title>MercadoLivre - Ocorreu um erro</title><link rel=stylesheet href="/css/null/7.0.5/errorPage.css"/><!--[if lt IE 7 ]><script src="http://www.mercadolibre.com/org-img/pcorner/js/dd_belatedPNG.min.js"></script><script> DD_belatedPNG.fix('img, .ico, .png24fix, .ch-expando-trigger'); //fix any <img> or .ico background-images </script><![endif]--><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//http2.mlstatic.com/ui/navigation/1.5.9/mercadolibre/favicon.ico"/></head><body data-country=AR><div class=errorPage500><p class=ups>Ops!</p><div class=errorMessage><h2>Ocorreu um erro</h2><p>Por favor, tente mais tarde.</p></div></div></body></html>
<!--
    Stats
    Generate time       : 36 ms
    Render time         : 1 ms
    Compress time       : 1 ms
    Total time          : 38 ms
    HostName            : i-3647d238-10.17.67.12
-->
```

> I guess problem may be your version mine python version is 3.4.2
>   Requests is 2.11.1

Comment: Actually the Json version does not work, since the output is different. It says "MercadoLivre - Ocorreu um erro". When I use the suggested method by postman, the result is different with a message saying the email is already in use.